# iText change cell height on page split

Tags: c#, itext

I have added a PdfPTable table similar to this in iTextSharp.

**Table**:

```
| Col1 | Col2  |
|------|-------|
|              |
|  Cell1       |
|              |
|--------------|
|  Cell2       |
|--------------|
|              |
|  Cell3       |
|--------------|
```

What I want, is that if page splits, then Cell1 MinimumHeight is resized to fit one page along with Cell2 and Cell3 is added to the new page. For example:

**Page1**

```
| Col1 | Col2  |
|------|-------|
|              |
|  Cell1       |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|--------------|
|  Cell2       |
|--------------|
```

**Page2**

```
|              |
|  Cell3       |
|--------------|
```

I tried setting the property of PdfPTable ExtendLastRow but this extends Cell2 in the first page and Cell3 in the second page, and I just want Cell 1 to be resized.

```
pdfPTable.ExtendLastRow = true;
```

Is there anyway?

Comment: No, that only works if you do the Math to calculate the heights. If Cell2 can be repeated as a footer row, there might be a way, but I don't think so.

Comment: @Bruno thank you for answer. So, is there a way or event that let me know when page split and so I can do the math to resize Cell 1? Cell2 is not the footer by the way

Comment: There is an event that warns you before and after the table splits; there is even an event that tells you want a page ends and starts, but at that time it's already too late: the table has already been drawn, and changing the cell won't have any effect. Tweaking the renderers in iText 7 might offer a solution, but you're still using iText 5 and you don't have access to the renderers in iText 5.

Comment: Well, I think that the only way is then set SplitLate property to false to avoid the blank space left by Cell3 when page split. Thank you Bruno.